# Почему "выглядИШЬ" ?

Tags: орфография

**Почему "выглядИШЬ"?**

Ведь глагол первого спряжения - выглянуть.

Answer (score 6):

По инфинитиву определяется спряжение только глаголов с безударным личным окончанием. В слове "глядИшь" - окончание ударное (И - значит " спряжение). Приставка спряжения не меняет. Особенность приставки "ВЫ" в том, что она перетягивает на себя ударение. Поэтому, если Вам встретился глагол с приставкой "ВЫ", прежде всего надо убрать приставку.
 Вылет..т - летИт (2 спряжение), выгляд...т - глядИт (2 спр.) , вынес...т - несЁт(Ё - первое спряжение). Выброс...т- брОс...т, окончание осталось безударным, определяю спряжение по инфинитиву: бросить, на -ить, 2 спряжение, пишу И - бросИт.

Comment: синхрон...

Comment: Еще примеры: спишь - выспишься, хотя спать, казалось бы, глагол 1 спряжения; льешь - выльешь, хотя "лить" оканчивается на -ить, как во 2 спряжении

Answer (score 2):

Выглянуть - это другой глагол.
Ориентироваться надо на "выглядеть". Без приставки он имеет формы с ударными личными окончаниями (суффиксами?) - глядим, глядишь, глядят, поэтому в список глаголов-исключений, предназначеннных для запоминания, не входит.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, выглянуть - это другой глагол. Он сов. вида. А "выглядишь" - несов. вида. Приставка "вы" действительно перетягивает ударение.